# Permutation counter and returning multidimensional vectors

Tags: c++, permutation, counter

I have my C++ code with repetitive permutations with bounds. My problem is returning two vectors (named process, z), one showing the number of elements in created permutation (one dimensional vector with ColIdx representing the indices of permutation), and another listing each element of permutation ( two dimensional vector).

```
void permute (vector<int>& qcassgn, vector<int>& start, 
              int qcsize, int bound, int colIdx, 
              vector<int>& process, vector<vector< int >> &z){  
 int sum=0;
 for (int i=0; i< start.size(); i++) {
    sum+= start[i]; 
 }
 if (sum >= bound) {
    process[colIdx]= start.size();
    for (int n=0; n< start.size(); n++) {
       z[colIdx][n] = start[n] ;
       cout << start[n] << " " ;}
       cout << "\t" << process[colIdx] ;
       cout << "\t" << colIdx << "\n"; 
       return;         
    }

    for (int i= 0; i < qcsize; i++) {   
       vector<int> newStart(start);
       newStart.push_back(qcassgn[i]);
       permute (qcassgn, newStart, qcsize, bound, (colIdx+i), process, z); 
    }
  }

main() { 
  ...
  for (j=0; j< qcsize; j++) { 
    newarray[0]=result[j];
    permute(result, newarray, qcsize, counter[i][s], colIdx, process, z); 
  }
  ...
}
```

The idea seems to be working however my colIdx can not calculate the right indice for generated permutation. I can not calculate the right colIdx. Additionally, my two dimensional vector gave vector outof range error.
-What is the right way to illustrate counter of ColIdx for such a representation
-How can I solve range problem with two dimensional vector.
Thx in advance

Example: Result array=[2,3,4], bound=10

Correct results are written for permutation, but not for its index and elements:

```
[2 2 2 2 2]    5    1  
[2 2 2 2 3]    5    2  
[2 2 2 2 4]    5    3  
[2 2 2 3 2]    5    2 (I want it to be 4)  
[2 2 2 3 3]    5    3 (I want it to be 5)   
[2 2 2 4]      4    3 ...
```

Comment: It is not clear why you are calling this "permutation". You are apparently copying the input vector preserving its order. No permutation seems to take place. If you post an example of input dataset and the desired result, it would be easier to reason about this.

Comment: @nm The idea of permutation is utilized (It is not exactly permutation). My problem is not able to generate correct index for created permutation, and assignment of z (two dimensional vector).